# Find string greater than (x) in length

Tags: python

How can I search through a variable and look for a word/string that is greater than 20 in length?

```
var = '''this is my example and I want
no find the following
string jakjajsiwjsjwijaksjdfjaiwjalskdjfiajwlajfklajsdfwi 
from this variable'''
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
print [x for x in var.split() if len(x) > 20]
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through a list of the words using `split` and check the `len` of each word.

```
for x in var.split():
    if len(x) > 20:
        print(x)
```

Or of course you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
long_words = [x for x in var.split() if len(x) > 20]
print(long_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var_split = var.split(' ')
long_word = ''

for word in var_split:
    if len(word) > 20:
        long_word = word
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence=input("enter the sentence")
max_length=int(input("enter the max length"))
sentence=sentence+" "
s=len(sentence)
d=0

for i in range(s):
    if(sentence[i]==" "):
        sum=i-d

        if(sum>max_length):
            for o in range(d,i):
                print(sentence[o],end="")
            print(end=" ")
        d=i+1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).